# Vector values overwritten by last value in a loop

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, vector, point-cloud-library

I have the vector to store pointers of point clouds:

```
std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<PointType>::Ptr> List;
```

In a loop I am trying to push_back point cloud pointers in it.

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr  cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

while(condition)
{...    
    List.push_back(cloud);
cloud->clear();
}
```

It adds point clouds, but at each iteration all values stored in the vector previously are replaced by the newly added value.

So lets say the size of the last point cloud I added is 400 and I added 5 point clouds in the iteration.

After the loop, if I check the sizes of stored 5 clouds, the results will be 
400
400
400
400
400

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: *"...but at each iteration..."* I don't see a loop, so how can we identify the problem?

Comment: It looks like you are reusing the same pointer over and over and change the pointed-to object in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks very much like you only create one point cloud, and in every iteration of your loop, you modify the point cloud, add a(nother) pointer to it to the vector, and repeat.

In other words, all your vector entries point to the same cloud, so every modification is of course visible through all entries.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than re-using your `cloud` variable over and over, which is the source of your issue, I would cut out the middle man

```
while(condition)
{   ...    
    List.emplace_back(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
}
```